# Running scala application for linux on windows 8.1

Tags: java, linux, windows, scala, web-applications

I am trying to run my scala application built for linux on windows 8.1. Building and initial run is successful but when trying further operations it is failing. The reason for it is not able to find the location of few files which are defined on linux file system location (such as: \var\log\myapplog\app.log or \tmp\keys.mykey). Is there any way by which we can run this application successfully without redefining the file location for windows file system?
some way by which we can simulate the linux file system?

Thanks

Comment: Your problems have nothing to do with scala which works fine on windows - you should ask about the specific program.

Comment: yes it works fine on windows but my question is if it's built to run on linux then is there any tool or procedure to run that application on windows without changing the file paths it's accessing?

Comment: You could create these paths (perhaps by installing cygwin or msys), or you could run a linux VM using something like virtualbox. But honestly you would be better off asking the makers of this specific application (or checking its configuration files to see if you can change the paths).